# Changing the size of labels of plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using [GetDist](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot_gallery.html) for plotting contours in `jupyter`. I am wondering how to change the size of numbers in axes and labels of parameters.
There are some lines in the code containing labels as follows:

```
a,b,c = np.genfromtxt('data/data.txt',unpack=True)
names = ['H','M','z']
labels =  ['H','M','z']
samples0 = MCSamples(samples=[a,b,c],names = names, labels = labels)
g.triangle_plot([samples0],['H','M','z'],legend_labels=['Summation of data'], legend_loc='upper right',filled=True)
```

The problem is when the number of parameter goes up, the plot should be smaller to placed in a printed paper and then we cannot see numbers and parameters' labels.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer which is tricky

```
g.settings.axes_fontsize = 20
g.settings.lab_fontsize = 30
g.settings.x_label_rotation=47
g.settings.legend_fontsize = 40
```

by the use of `g.setting` in `GetDist` we can customize the plots.

Comment: this is not working for me... Idk why ..

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `plot.legend(loc=2, prop={'size': 6})` to increase the legend size This takes a dictionary of keywords corresponding to `matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties` properties. [more about legends](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend)

1). if you want to increase the size of the plotting data according to x values this would be helpful.

`# yvalues is the y value list
widthscale = len(yvalues)/4 
figsize = (8*widthscale,6) # fig size in inches (width,height)
figure = pylab.figure(figsize = figsize) # set the figsize`

if you want increase them without dynamically you can use [plot.rc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rc.html) function
eg.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SMALL_SIZE = 8
MEDIUM_SIZE = 10
BIGGER_SIZE = 12

plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=SMALL_SIZE)     # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # fontsize of the figure title
```

2).second option would be

```
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 22
```

or directly control the size of the label

```
ax.set_xlabel("some label", fontsize=22)
```

To control the legend's fontsize you can use rcParams

```
plt.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 22
```

or directly specify the size in the legend

```
ax.legend(fontsize=22)
```

Comment: Thank you but I want to change the size of numbers and the lables of axes, not legends.

Comment: so, why I cannot see it? `figsize`? `widthscale`? where is lables and names? font?

Comment: i have edited the answer i think i have given the solution what you've looking for

Comment: Yes but the problem is when I put them in code, the code runs, but there is no changes in output's plot

Comment: Try the 2 nd option!!

Comment: Thank you, I will do it and will let you know and then mark the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font size of the labels to adjust them so they are more visible. If you can edit your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) by adding some dummy data and your plotting code, it will be much easier to provide more specific help.