# Font size of x and y label with triangle_plot

Tags: python, plot, triangle

I want to increase the fontsize of the x and y label of my triangle plot. I tried as in this question: [Changing the size of labels of plots in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188585/changing-the-size-of-labels-of-plots-in-python)
but it's not working for me... here is my code

```
import getdist.plots as gdplt
from getdist.mcsamples import loadMCSamples
from getdist.mcsamples import MCSamplesFromCobaya
from getdist import plots, MCSamples
.
.
.
names2 = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", 'p7']
labels2 =  my_head_new[2:9]
samples2 = MCSamples(samples = sample[burn:,2:9], names = names2, labels = labels2)#, settings={'smooth_scale_2D':0.3})
plt.figure()
g = plots.getSubplotPlotter()
g.triangle_plot(samples2, filled=True)
g.settings.lab_fontsize = 40
g.settings.axes_fontsize = 40
plt.suptitle(r'Test92: vanilla + $\Omega_k$' + '\n nlive: 10d \n log(Z)= -315.98598 $\pm$ 0.66455', ha ='center', va='bottom', fontsize = 25)
plt.savefig('plot_triangle_vanilla_92_burned.png', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close('all')
```

Does anyone know why? This is the produced figure as proof that the font is very small

[image]

How can I increase the font, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that

```
g.settings.lab_fontsize = 40
g.settings.axes_fontsize = 40
```

was **after**

```
g.triangle_plot(samples2, filled=True)
```

putting it before solved the problem.